# Get column name of the first non-zero column where there are multiple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame filled with customers and their transactions by the week. My goal is to add to this to understand when the first sale happened.

`customer_df`

```
CUST_ID |   2021-01-01| 2021-01-08| ... | 2023-03-28
ADS49485|  0          |   0       |     | 1.482
ADS49644|  0          |   .975    |     | 2.584
ADS31234|  0          |   0       |     | 0
```

I want to add a column that finds the first instance of a value greater than zero and records the column name where it occurs.

`output_df`

```
CUST_ID |   2021-01-01  | 2021-01-08| ... | 2023-03-28 | first_sale
ADS49485|  0          |   0       |     | 1.482      |2023-03-28
ADS49644|  0          |   .975    |     | 2.584      |2021-01-08
ADS31234|  0          |   0       |     | 0          |2022-12-01
```

I was using `idmax` however its returning the max non-zero value and not the first instance of it.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try `idxmax`

```
df['new'] = df.ne(0).mask(lambda x : x==0).iloc[:,1:].idxmax(axis=1)
Out[15]: 
0    2023-03-28
1    2021-01-08
2    2021-01-01
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) on the boolean DataFrame of non-zero, values. Also, to handle the case in which there is no match, you must add an extra check with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)+[`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
m = df.drop(columns='CUST_ID').ne(0)
df['first_sale'] = m.idxmax(axis=1).where(m.any(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
    CUST_ID  2021-01-01  2021-01-08  2023-03-28  first_sale
0  ADS49485           0       0.000       1.482  2023-03-28
1  ADS49644           0       0.975       2.584  2021-01-08
2  ADS31234           0       0.000       0.000         NaN
```

Intermediate `m`:

```
   2021-01-01  2021-01-08  2023-03-28
0       False       False        True
1       False        True        True
2       False       False       False # here idxmax would return 2021-01-01
                                      # we need to mask it
```

`m.any(axis=1)`:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just use the lambda function to iterate the values and then find the column which has the value > 0

```
# Add a new column with column names having values greater than 0
df['first_sale'] = df.apply(lambda row: ', '.join(row.index[row > 0]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Since there are multiple instances of a value greater than 0, this returns all the column names where the value is greater than 0. Is there a way I can only return the first instance?